# How to create a command to create a view in laravel version 5.8.23?

Tags: laravel, makefile, view

I want to create a command to create views by promp, I know it is possible, I saw examples in the laravel documentation but I could not understand :(

Comment: take  a look at the command section https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan

Comment: Here's a simple tutorial: https://medium.com/@imfx/create-make-custom-commands-in-laravel-9fa002da582e